# Long press possible on child item of HorizontalScrollView?

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I'm having a problem implementing a long press within my custom view, based on a `HorizontalScrollView`.

The `HorizontalScrollView` has a child `LinearLayout`, which in turn has a child View.  The View draws bitmaps to the canvas via `OnDraw()`.

I'd like to allow the `HorizontalScrollView` to scroll normally, either fast or slow.  But, if the user holds their finger (even if scrolling) on one of the images, it would immediately cancel the scrolling and allow the user to perform a function with the selected image.  (In this particular case, they'd be moving the image around the screen, but it could really be any number of functions.)

I've tried many combinations of handling the events (true, false, super) within each layer (`HorizontalScrollView` and `View`) but none seem to work 100%.  Some combinations get there most of the way, some others part of the way, but they always seem to be missing one feature or another (scroll, hit test, etc.).

The closest I've gotten is to return false within the `HorizontalScrollView's` `onInterceptTouchEvent()` and true within the View's `onTouch()` event.  This allows the scroll and also registers the hit test on the image.  But, it immediately passes control back to the onTouch() event of the `HorizontalScrollView`.  That makes it impossible to check if the image has been pressed for a number of seconds (long press).

If I return true within the View's `onTouch()` event, the hit test registers, and I'm able to check if the user has long pressed the image within `ACTION_MOVE`.  But, then the `HorizontalScrollView` doesn't scroll.

Am I missing something completely obvious, or have I simply chosen two views that don't play well together?  Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

right,

dont know if you have sorted this or not, I have mashed some bits together that I think do what you ask, if not then hey ho.

I have an activity that loads in the horizontal scroller, this might not be the best way but it works for me:

HolderActivity class (the one that loads in the HorizontalScrollView class) I have:

```
int selectedItem;
public boolean onLongClick(View v, int position) {
    selectedItem = position;
    openContextMenu(v);
    return true;
}

public boolean onItemClick(int position) {)//do what you want here on click (press)


@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
    ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

     String[] menuItems = {"Menu item 1 text", "Cancel"};
     for (int i = 0; i<menuItems.length; i++) {
       menu.add(Menu.NONE, i, i, menuItemsRemove[i]);
    }
     menu.setHeaderTitle("My menu title");
}
```

in your HorizontalScrollView class's constructor pass I pass through a context in there like so:

```
public MyScroller(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
}
```

I have a method for creating the items from an ArrayList called setFeatureItems like so:

```
public void setFeatureItems(ArrayList<MyListEntity> items){}
```

Within this method I add a GestureDetector passing the context to it to each item like so:

```
mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new MyGestureDetector());
```

And the MyGestureDetector nested class  which has the reference to the all important parentActivity is like this:

```
class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent arg0) {
            parentActivity.onLongClick(MyScroller.this, mActiveFeature);
        };

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent arg0) {
            parentActivity.onItemClick(mActiveFeature);
            return true;
        };

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            try {
                //right to left
                if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    int featureWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
                    mActiveFeature = (mActiveFeature < (mItems.size() - 1))? mActiveFeature + 1:mItems.size() -1;
                    smoothScrollTo(mActiveFeature*featureWidth, 0);
                    return true;
                }
                //left to right
                else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    int featureWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
                    mActiveFeature = (mActiveFeature > 0)? mActiveFeature - 1:0;
                    smoothScrollTo(mActiveFeature*featureWidth, 0);
                    return true;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Fling", "There was an error processing the Fling event:" + e.getMessage());
            }
            return false;
        }
}
```

I have cut this from an existing proj so there might be remnants where I have not made it generic enough, I hope this makes sense or helps, let me know If i can add any more detail